# Run a script on a spreadsheet, or a specific sheet within a spreadsheet, and pull data conditionally to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

This is my 2nd question, as the first one was solved by patt0, thanks!

I have an on edit working script that is checking everytime I edit a sheet and, if the value of any cell of the column no. 7 is changed to "RECEBER", it will pull the entire row to another sheet. At first, I tought that would work for me, but quickly found out that the onEdit has some limitations that aren't compatible with what I want to do.

Since I cannot rely on the onEdit, I want to run the script from a menu that was created (as suggested by patt0) whenever I want. This could be done all at once, to a whole spredsheet, and also sheet by sheet (I believe the solution to both will be similar, and both ways would be very handy for me).

here's the code I have (not working - was adapted from the previous on edit code):

This first part is storing the sheet name to check if it is between 1 and 31;

```js
function mustBeCopied(sheetName) {
  var sheetNumber = parseInt(sheetName);
  if (sheetNumber <=31 && sheetNumber >=1)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

This second part probably as some issues,as it was brought from the onEdit function.

```js
function RECEBER() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // stores the active spreadsheet (where the script is being ran)
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet(); // stores the Active sheet within the stored spreadsheet
  var r = ss.getActiveRange(); // stores the range of rows in my document ?
  if(mustBeCopied(s.getName()) && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "RECEBER") { // if mustBeCopied, when applied to the sheet defined in the s variable is satisfied, it will check on every row if the value "RECEBER" is in its 7th column.
    var row = r.getRow(); // stores the row that satisfied the condition
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn(); // stores the last column on the sheet ?
    var targetSheet = s.getSheetByName("money"); // sets the target sheet
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); // gets range on the target sheet and adds one more row for the new data to be inserted
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target); // writes the data into the target sheet, but I don't understand how..
  }
}
```

I'm doing a step by step analysis to see if I'm understanding what's happening..

I'm sure this can be done quite easily, and am wiling to learn, but I can't seem to find solutions on the net.. I thought this would be already a discussed subject.
It would save me a lot of time every month if I could do this automatically. It would also decrease the risk of human error, as it would be handled by computer..

I hope someone can help me..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Execution transcript (View -> Execution transcript) to observe the execution stack (any errors will be there).

The following code may be helpful:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onEdit(e) {
  var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('money'), 
      range = e.range,
      s = range.getSheet(),
      lastColumn = s.getLastColumn();
  if (mustBeCopied(s.getName()) && range.getColumn() === 7 && e.value === 'RECEBER')
    s.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, lastColumn).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn));
}
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But the onEdit won't work for me, it doesn't respond to the paste command. Also, as data is manually inserted into the sheet, once the column 7 is filled with the value that satisfies the condition, the rest of the data to be filled won't be copied, as the function has already been triggered..

Comment: @DiogoSousa Take the best of the answer, for example, check the Execution transcript to see errors. The line, `var targetSheet = s.getSheetByName("money");` should be giving error because `s` (Sheet) do not have the method `getSheetByName`. The code is just a reference to apply it to your code.

Comment: I understand what you say, but the getSheetByName hasn't been a problem on the onEdit function.. so why would it not work now?

Comment: @DiogoSousa When I run your code I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetByName in object Sheet` on the line: `var targetSheet = s.getSheetByName("money");`. It would be necessary to review that.

Comment: why did it work for the onEdit code that I had previously? it was working fine, everytime I edited the sheet to meet the conditions mentioned in the function, it would successfully write the row data into the money sheet..

Comment: This is the log that I get when I run the execution script:
[13-10-13 10:36:54:524 BST] Starting execution
[13-10-13 10:36:54:535 BST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[13-10-13 10:36:54:535 BST] Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[13-10-13 10:36:54:535 BST] Spreadsheet.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
[13-10-13 10:37:02:971 BST] Sheet.getName() [8.435 seconds]
[13-10-13 10:37:02:971 BST] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
[13-10-13 10:37:03:070 BST] Execution succeeded [8.437 seconds total runtime]

Comment: @DiogoSousa As shown in the Execution transcript, the `IF` is not met, therefore, does not run the inside of the `IF`.

Comment: I can't make sense out of this.. I understand what you're saying, but I can't manage to put on a working code..